# I made a widget button which works with pending intent. Why does it just work once?

Tags: android, button, widget

I made a widget on Android Studios which contains a button. The button should normally increase a number and change the text of a Textview to that number. The number, and therefore the number in the Textview, should increase with every click. The problem now is that everything works just fine(no errors, nothing), but the button works just once and the number just increases once.

I have no idea where the problem might lie.

With the same procedure I tried changing the background to a random color with every click and it works just fine and the

**WidgetProvider**

```
public class WidgetProvider1 extends AppWidgetProvider {

    String widgettextviewtext;
    final String INCREASENUMBER= "sdfjkldjldkf";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.increase_button,onClickPendingIntent(context,INCREASENUMBER) );

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);


        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }


    int number=1;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

        if(intent.getAction() == BACKGROUNDCOLORACTION){
            number = number +1;
            String text=""+zahl;
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView, text);


            updateWidgetNow(context, remoteViews);
        }


        if(intent.hasExtra("ETTEXTEXTRAKEY")){
            widgettextviewtext = intent.getStringExtra("ETTEXTEXTRAKEY");
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView, widgettextviewtext);
            updateWidgetNow(context, remoteViews);
        }


        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }

    public void updateWidgetNow (Context context, RemoteViews remoteViews){
        ComponentName widgetComponent = new ComponentName(context, WidgetProvider1.class);
        AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(widgetComponent, remoteViews);
    }


    public PendingIntent onClickPendingIntent (Context context, String stringAction){

        Intent onClickIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetProvider1.class);
        onClickIntent.setAction(stringAction);

        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,onClickIntent,0);
    }
    
}
```

**widgetlayout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00bbff"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
    android:id="@+id/widget_layout"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="15"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="App öffnen"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```